# Foundation 6 in IE, breaks on ES2015 JS template syntax?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, zurb-foundation

I've recently included Foundation 6.2.2 core js in a site, and upon checking it in IE (multi-versions) and it chokes ES2015 *template syntax*. However, I am not finding much info about this feature's support. It is completely missed from this chart:

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Here is an example:

```
if(!plugin.$element.attr(`data-${pluginName}`)) { ...
```

Does anybody have information on the support of JS templates across browsers?

Comment: Well have you tried https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/???

Comment: Duh. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ - the template syntax is not available.

However, I understand that Babel is a tool meant to provide future JS support now:
https://babeljs.io/